# Creating a List of permutations given a condition with GAP system

Tags: gap

Please, I am new to GAP system and I am trying to test the following simplified form of code where I intend to test a given condition on a set of permutations and then add to the list M  of the permutations satisfying the given equation. The aim is to figure the suitable values of the variables a and b.

```
>S:=[1,2,3];; T:=[1,2,3];; M:=[];;
>for a in S do for b in T
>do if b<>a and (1,a)*(b,3)=(1,2,3) then 
>Add(M, [[1, a], [b,3]]); fi; od; od;
>M;
```

Here is the error message I got

```
Syntax error:      :=   expected
M;
 ^
```

Please if I could get this code fixed or an alternative way of achieving similar goal. Below is my expected result:

```
[[[1,2],[1,3]],[[1,3],[2,3]]].
```

Comment: I tried the code and got the error message "Error, Permutation: cycles must be disjoint" because when a=1 you get the permutation (1,a)=(1,1), and GAP does not accept (1,1) as a valid input for a permutation.

Comment: I was able to get the expected result with the following modified code so we do not try to input (1,1) or (3,3) as a permutation (GAP does not like that):  S:=[1,2,3];; T:=[1,2,3];; M:=[];;
S:=[1,2,3];; T:=[1,2,3];; M:=[];; for a in S do for b in T do if b<>a and a<>1 and b<>3 then if (1,a)*(b,3)=(1,2,3) then Add(M,[[1,a],[b,3]]); fi; fi; od; od;